# using rbind is adding data to dataframe as column not row in r

Tags: r, rbind

I want to add this data to my dataframe as a row not a column.

```
df = data.frame('symbol'= character(0), 'price_last'= integer(0), 
                                    'Momentum_Index'= integer(0))
symbol = 'ABC'
price_last = 219
Momentum_Index = 96
df <- rbind(df,symbol,price_last,Momentum_Index)
```

df shows the data as a column instead of a row.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to initialise a data frame (or objects in general) in R. Just do `data.frame(symbol, price_last, Momentum_Index)`

Answer (score 1):

What is happening in your code is that you aren't trying to bind two rows together. You are binding an empty row with 3 different objects. `rbind` guesses that those objects are part of the same column because none of the objects have a column name attribute (so the column they should go in is NA), and you end up with everything in the same column.

```
df = data.frame('symbol'= character(0), 'price_last'= integer(0), 
                'Momentum_Index'= integer(0))
symbol = 'ABC'
price_last = 219
Momentum_Index = 96

df <- rbind(df,symbol,price_last,Momentum_Index)
#   c..ABC....219....96..
# 1                   ABC
# 2                   219
# 3                    96
```

Instead you need the data you want to bind to be in row format where each column of data has a column name attribute:

```
df1 = data.frame('symbol'= character(0), 'price_last'= integer(0), 
                'Momentum_Index'= integer(0))
df2 = df = data.frame('symbol'= 'ABC', 'price_last'= 219, 
                      'Momentum_Index'= 96)

df <- rbind(df1,df2)
#   symbol price_last Momentum_Index
# 1    ABC        219             96
```

There is one final problem with your code that won't be an issue here, but that will be an issue for you in the future. You are using left quotes `'<object>'` instead of using right quotes. In your case you can either leave the single quotes off of the column names or you can change the left quotes to right quotes. This is important if you were to try to name a column with a space in the column name such as `my column name = character()`. The right facing quote is located above the tilde (~) key.

Examples of more correct quotes:

```
df1 = data.frame(symbol= character(0), price_last= integer(0), 
                 Momentum_Index= integer(0))
df1 = data.frame(`symbol`= character(0), `price_last`= integer(0), 
                 `Momentum_Index`= integer(0))
```

P.S. You rarely have to declare an empty dataframe. I'm going to assume you're needing the empty dataframe for some sort of loop action that you are taking.

Comment: If there is some reason you don't want to just declare another data.frame object there are other ways to handle this. But I'm going to stick to the scope of the question.

Answer (score -1):

the given example doesn't work very well, but let's say you have a data frame df and you want to add a row to it , it will be :

```
df <- rbind(df, c(symbol,price_last,Momentum_Index))
```

the idea is to bind the data frame to a `vector` that you create by using the letter `c`
as in `c(symbol,price_last,Momentum_Index)`